# Htaccess Rewrite Not Found

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, file-not-found

I'm using **Mod Rewrite** to remove index.php. I do not want to use queries. I want **foo.com/bar** to be interpreted as **foo.com/index.php/bar**.

It does this fine, but gives me **Not Found error**. The requested URL /home/foo/www/index.php/bar was not found on this server.

*Why!!*

Comment: @Luke, I updated my answer. I think I might understand what you are wanting to do, so let me know if I missed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

I think I just figured out what you are wanting to do. You see, you can pass queries behind the scenes, but you cannot pass what you are suggesting behind the scenes. You have to do an actual redirect. Something like this (The important part is the `R`):

```
RewriteRule ^bar$ index.php/bar [NC,QSA,R]
```

This forces a redirect to your page using the new special path. Is that what you wanted?

**Original Answer**

You cannot pass a path to a PHP page like that as it *will be interpreted as part of a path*. Chances are, your file is on a Linux/Unix machine where a directory can be named with a `.` in it. Sorry, but you will have to use a query string:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^bar$ index.php?page=bar [NC,QSA]
```

**Or** *updated*:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^bar$ index.php?/bar [NC,QSA]
```

I also think the last few versions of windows support `.` in directories as well, but I am not sure.

Comment: Yes, Windows will allow `.` in directories.

Comment: I'm looking for a segmented approach, instead of by query. Code Igniter uses it, I believe. Unless they're just sneaky about it.

http://bit.ly/bGdA8n

Comment: @Luke, read through that whole link you shared. You'll see their 'Online Solution' is actually `index.php?/bar` which still uses the query string, just without a variable name.

Comment: Ah! Fabulous! That's it. Thank you Doug!

Comment: @Luke Burns No problem man, sorry I misunderstood what you wanted at first! Good luck on your project!

Answer (score 0):

`index.php` is almost certainly a file, not a directory, unless you (bizarrely) have a directory called `index.php`. Apache is correctly complaining that there is no such directory.

You probably meant to do something like `index.php?page=bar`. Adjust your `.htaccess` accordingly.

Comment: Oh, it's treating it like a directory?

What can I do if I don't want to use queries?